# Using a ios .framework in Qt App

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, qt, cocoa

I have tried a lot of searching to see if there are similar questions as mine. But really couldn't find any question which accurately answers what I am looking for.
Following is something similar but the suggestion in answer does not work
[Can't add iOS OpenCV Framework in a QT Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008777/cant-add-ios-opencv-framework-in-a-qt-project)

Hence, framing my question. Following is my question:
What I am trying to do is pretty basic though.
I have built a cocoa touch framework using XCode. It is built successfully & the .framework is located in a location like below
//Users/rb/Mybinaries/myframework.framework

I have a public class in the framework module with a public function that one can call in.

Next I want to use it in a Qt application that is built using Qt 5.5 for iOS platform. The runs fine on my iPhone.

But I am not able to figure out how I can link this .framework (cocoa touch framework.. *not static framework*) to my Qt app & call into this exposed method.

Got to know that following should work:
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -F//Users/rb/Mybinaries/...(location to framework folder)
LIBS += -framework myframework

But after this, I am not able to include the header file in the framework to call my method. I know that I can mix swift & Qt in one project. But I am interested to know if we can dynamically link to a cocoa .framework & invoke an exposed method in the cocoa framework.

Also would be helpful if there is a working sample somewhere.

Thanks a many in advance.

Comment: I guess it depends on what the framework exposes.  It could be C, Objective-C or C++.  Qt will only be able to use C and C++.

Comment: But is it not possible to call into the static framework from Qt by somehow including it in the .pro file ?